# radicality vs. radicalness

Tags: synonyms, expression-choice

I have a question with regards to the use of *radicality* or *radicalness*. I am not quite sure which one to use or what the differences are.

I use these terms in reference to political parties and protest movements. Say, for instance, in the sentence: "Radicality/radicalness is a defining characteristic of populist right movements, both in the electoral and in the protest arena."

Wiktionary suggests that both exist, but [radicality](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radicalness) is the more commonly used form. For me, they both sound the same. What do you think, is there a difference?

Comment: Google Ngrams seem to indicate that 'radicality' became the favoured form in the late 1970s. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Wiktionary is not a reliable source for frequency of use.

Comment: It's a fine line, but to me, *radicality* sounds more like a clinical category whereas *radicalness* is more suggestive of actually being radical. Kind of like, say, *space* vs *spaciousness*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is the same and according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=radicality%2Cradicalness&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cradicality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cradicalness%3B%2Cc0) usage of radicalism was more commonly used from
the ‘80s.